# Como adicionar nova linha em tabela com conteudo a partir de caixa de texto com post ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Eu tenho uma tabela criada usando html e javascript, o conteudo dela eu usei o metodo de GET do ajax para puxar de uma url, em JSON. Eu estou tentando agora usando POST no ajax adicionar conteudo a essa tabela, onde eu escrevo em duas caixas de texto o numero de um codigo e o nome de um produto e ao clicar no botao gravar ele crie mais uma linha na tabela com os valores que eu coloquei. Alguem pode me dar uma luz?

Segue o HTML:

```
<div class="card-body" style="background-color:#262626">

             <table class="table  table-hover table-bordered" id="dataTable"  >

                <tbody>


              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<a><button class="btn" id="popuplink" style= "background-color:#C25C40; border-color:#C25C40; position:absolute; left:850px; top:55px; color:white;">Novo grupo</button></a>
            </div>
            <div id="popup">
<div id="content">
<input id="popupcodigo" type="text" placeholder="codigo"></input>
<input id="popupgrupo" type="text" placeholder="grupo"></input>
<input id="popupinativo" type="text" placeholder="inativo"></input>
    <input id="popupclose" type="Button" value="Gravar"/>   
 </div>   

</div>
```

Segue o javascript com ajax:

```
$(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "http://url-usada/",

    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache:false,
    success: function(data){

        var event_data = '';

            //começo da tabela
            event_data += '<thead>';
            event_data += '<tr style="color:white">';
            event_data += '<th width="10%">Código</th>';
            event_data += '<th>Grupo</th>';
            event_data += '<th>Inativo</th>';
            event_data += '<th width="10%">Ação</th>';
            event_data += '</tr>';  
            event_data += '</thead>';   

            //final da tabela
            event_data += '<tfoot>';
            event_data += ' <tr style="color:white">';
            event_data += '  <th width="10%">Código</th>';
            event_data += ' <th>Grupo</th>';
            event_data += '  <th>Inativo</th>';
            event_data += ' <th width="17%">Ação</th>';
            event_data += ' </tr>';
            event_data += '</tfoot>';

        //conteudo da tabela vindo da url
        $.each(data, function(index, value){

            event_data += '<tr>';
            event_data += '<td>'+value.Cdgrupo+'</td>';
            event_data += '<td>'+value.Grupos+'</td>';
            event_data += '<td>'+value.Inativo+'</td>';
            event_data += '<td><a href="alterar-grupoc.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info mesmo-tamanho" title="Alterar Grupo"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></a> <a href="404.html" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mesmo-tamanho" title="Excluir Grupo"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></a></td>';
            event_data += '</tr>';
        });


        $('#dataTable').css({'color':'white'});
        $("#dataTable").append(event_data);
    },

    //aviso de erro caso o conteudo da tabela não seja carregado
    error: function(d){

        alert("Erro.");
    }


});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

"Se vc utiliza o `mysql` segue":

Como vc esta utilizando a `api datatable` aplica uma funçao de `reload` como retorno.

no retorno do `ajax` aplica isso:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload( null, false);
```

Comment: Não estou usando mysql e não entendi exatamente o que fazer

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você precisa incluir o jquery no seu html, no final da página (antes de incluir o seu script.js!):
[image: Exemplo de inclusão do jquery seguido do script.js]

Feito isso, você pode, colocar o seu HTML de adição de produtos dentro de uma tag de formulário:
[image: exemplo de form]

Lembrando que o seu botão gravar, será o botão de submit desse form e também, assim que clicado em gravar, esse evento irá chamar a sua função que possui a lógica para, com ajax, inserir uma nova linha com o produto adicionado:
[image: Botão gravar com submit e onClick para chamar função do script.js]

Feito isso, caso tenha dificuldades com o Jquery para fazer o que você precisa com o Ajax, você pode seguir esse artigo do devMedia que explica como utilizar o Ajax:
[AJAX Tutorial](https://www.devmedia.com.br/ajax-tutorial/24797)

Comment: O meu problema é especificamente no Jquery, o html está escrito corretamente.